Executable jar fails with java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "manifold.rt.api.util.Pair.getFirst()" because "classSymbol" is null
I have to create an executable jar that takes in some command line arguments to process a json file. It is supposed to dynamically create a java pojo out of the json using manfold libraries and then run an algorithm to determine results for a given persona to decide the order of content for that persona. the application runs fine on IntelliJ IDE but when I create the executable jar and run it I get:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-07-29T12:33:14.586-07:00 ERROR 35361 --- [algorithm] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "manifold.rt.api.util.Pair.getFirst()" because "classSymbol" is null
    at manifold.ext.DynamicProxyFactory.hasCallHandlerFromExtension(DynamicProxyFactory.java:117) ~[manifold-ext-2024.1.29.jar!/:2024.1.29]
    at manifold.ext.DynamicProxyFactory.hasCallHandlerMethod(DynamicProxyFactory.java:102) ~[manifold-ext-2024.1.29.jar!/:2024.1.29]
    at manifold.ext.DynamicProxyFactory.makeProxyFactory(DynamicProxyFactory.java:52) ~[manifold-ext-2024.1.29.jar!/:2024.1.29]
    at manifold.ext.rt.RuntimeMethods.createProxy(RuntimeMethods.java:415) ~[manifold-all-2024.1.29.jar!/:2024.1.29]
    at manifold.ext.rt.RuntimeMethods.createNewProxy(RuntimeMethods.java:387) ~[manifold-all-2024.1.29.jar!/:2024.1.29]
    at manifold.ext.rt.RuntimeMethods.constructProxy(RuntimeMethods.java:63) ~[manifold-all-2024.1.29.jar!/:2024.1.29]
    at org.sampler.algorithm.Algorithm.getPillarToJourneyMapping(Algorithm.java:178) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.sampler.algorithm.Algorithm.getPathwayForPersona(Algorithm.java:67) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.sampler.algorithm.Application.run(Application.java:182) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar!/:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/:3.3.1]
    at org.sampler.algorithm.Application.main(Application.java:40) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[algorithm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[algorithm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[algorithm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

I have checked several times on the build.gradle file setup options and also tried fatJar options but cannot get the jar to execute without this error. To me it looks like the manifold code is not able to create the Java from json when run on command line but it all works fine when running in IDE.

You are missing several details. Your gradle file, the application code (at very least the startup class), what steps are you taking to generate the jar file.

manifold-json does indeed work from both the IDE and the command line. There is probably an error in your gradle file regarding dependency config and/or jar packaging.
You can either add more information here or post a question/issue with attached info on the manifold github. Following up on github is usually a speedier process.

Thanks for your responses. since it is client code I am not able to share it here. Perhaps I will try to create a similar project on my personal repo and then share. For the time being, I removed all manifold dependencies and wrote my own code and it all works.
